# Converting character values to a numeric data type

Tags: r, gsub

I need help in converting character values such as "80.5K" or "5.79M" to a numeric data type.
I tried using the `gsub` function, but not sure on how to work with the numbers after the decimal point

```
gsub(pattern = "K", replacement = "" , "80.53K")
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987917/how-do-i-replace-k-and-m-with-thousands-and-millions or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159114/converting-unit-abbreviations-to-numbers ?

Comment: Thanks for this one , both the links were helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_number()` from `readr` library.

```
library(tidyverse)

value1 <- "80.5K"
parse_number(value1)


value2 <- "5.79M"
parse_number(value2)
```

Gives:

```
80.5
5.79
```

Reference - https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_number.html

Comment: Thanks for this one, will try this one out